# Name 'pytest' is not defined. how to run testpy?

Tags: python, pytest

I have installed python with conda.

```
pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.0.5, imported from /home/fabiano/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py
```

My test script

```
def tc1():
    given="49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d"
    expected=b"SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t"
    assert base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(given)) == expected
```

I have imported pytest

```
import pytest
```

I am trying some stuff with pytest.But when I try from Python shell,I  have problems like this

```
testset.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'testset' is not defined
```

In my shell
pytest

```
<module 'pytest' from '/home/fabiano/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py'>
```

Where should I save testset.py file?

Comment: Have you imported pytest in your python script? (could we get an example of your test script)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute `testset.py` from the python shell as if you were running as your standard shell.  Python does not treat everything as a string like, for example, bash does.

Comment: @KindStranger What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pytest does test discovery. The basic steps are well listed in their [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#python-test-discovery)

1. Name the file containing the test `test_*.py` or `*_test.py`.
2. Name the test functions in those files `def test_*`

For you test, place the following code in the file `test_set.py`:

```
import base64

def test_tc1():
    given="49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d"
    expected=b"SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t"
    assert base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(given)) == expected
```

Navigate to the directory containing the file `test_set.py` and execute the pytest command:

```
pytest
```

Expected output:

```
user@pc:/tmp/test_dir $ pytest .
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2+, pytest-3.0.3, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /tmp/test_dir , inifile:  collected 1 items 

test_set.py .

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```